# How to setup a serverless webhook for a macOS / iOS app?

Tags: swift, google-calendar-api, webhooks, serverless, appkit

For background, we have a standalone macOS / iOS app. These apps connect to Google Calendar to retrieve a user's calendar events. [Google Calendar supports notifying](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) clients (i.e. our app) of any changes that may occur remotely to an event via a webhook. We don't have a backend / cloud server.

Is there a service that allows one to setup a serverless webhook which also supports Push notifications (or direct network streaming) so that our app can be notified on-demand when there's a change? I wish to achieve this:

- Our app connects to Google Calendar
- Google Calendar notifies us of changes via the webhook (a serverless webhook)
- The serverless webhook notifies our app - i.e. the user's installed copy - (via Push / network connection that we opened at launch), passing on the notification as the payload, including headers etc.

Comment: did you find anything good?